# Uploading a tvOS application to iTunes Connect fails

Tags: app-store-connect, tvos

The news section in iTunes Connect says:

> You can now create and upload apps for the App Store on Apple TV

I've tried and got this error:

[image]

I've added a new tvOS target to an existing App, which is already available in the App Store. Both targets (iOS, tvOS) are using the same bundle identifier.

Does anyone have an idea of what went wrong or has anyone been able to successfully submit a built to iTunes Connect? The error message is not helpful.

Comment: Yeah, I've been getting the same thing as well. Can you try use Application Loader to upload to iTunes Connect, it has more details on why it failed. That way we can compare.

Comment: Application Loader worked. I've got a warning, that I need a GM version of XCode, but the build was submitted successfully and is shown in iTunesConnect

Comment: Awesome, looks like there's probably something still stuck on my end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the "Application Loader.app" of the current Xcode Beta to upload your binary.

Works for me.